# How to cash my brother's check

Tags: banking, check, checking-account, paycheck

My brother is 15 and he doesn’t have a bank account.  I’m 18 and I have a bank account. Would I be able to cash a work check written to him?

Comment: If this is a paycheck, shouldn't the plan be to open a bank account? So that he can use the money he is earning and not have to deposit into a relatives bank account every two week. Also specify the country in the question, and add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the jurisdiction and perhaps also the specific bank.

In Australia, for example, “cashing” a cheque means getting cash upon presentation of the cheque, without going through The waiting period associated with cheque clearance. I’d expect banks to be reluctant to cash cheques written out to specified payees.

If you don’t mind *banking/depositing* the cheque, you could ask your bank whether whether they would accept a cheque that your brother [endorsed](https://www.thebalance.com/how-to-endorse-checks-315300) to you. Some jurisdictions may even be willing to cash endorsed cheques.

Answer (score 2):

Most banks will cash checks that are written from their own accounts, because the bank can immediately check to see if the writer has the cash available to pay out instead of having to send the check to another bank, wait on them to transfer the funds, and so on.

So, if there is a branch of the bank the check was written from, take your brother to that branch and he should be able to get cash after signing.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend entirely upon the legal jurisdiction that you and your brother live in and the bank's policies.  In most jurisdictions, parents or legal guardians can endorse a check made payable to a child.  It would be most likely that the bank would require the check to be deposited and held until the drawing bank paid it.  The usual form in the US is "Bob Smith, Minor" with a new line of "by Angus Smith, father" and Angus' signature.

It is not impossible that the other bank could refuse to pay on a parent's endorsement.

For example, in the United States, the Code of Federal Regulations places restrictions on who can endorse a check for a minor and what things must happen for the endorsement to be valid.  See, for example, § 240.16

Each state has its own laws.

In the United States, most banks will require a bank account to exist for the minor, either jointly with the parent or a custodial account controlled by the parent until the child turns 18.  They will not allow the "cashing" of those checks, but, instead, require that they be deposited and held for collection from the other bank.  The account agreement will, almost certainly, state that the account's funds will be used for the benefit of the minor.

The short answer is, in the United States at least, "no" a brother would not usually be allowed to cash a check for a minor brother unless they were a legal guardian.